# Login username is not what is showing up in the terminal and chat icon

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, ldap

Im using openldap for login authentication, I have a 10.04 server and a 11.04 client.

I have 2 users set up so far, Mike and Alicia.

When I log in with alicias name, the chat status icon next to the power button says mike.
Also when you open up the terminal, it says mike@alicia-linux instead of alicia@alicia-linux.

If I click on the chat icon (that says mike) and click the about me option, it says user name alicia, and gives me all of alicia's information.

I don't get it?

When I type in getent passwd i have these 2 entries on the bottom.

```
mike:x:1000:10000:Mike Gaffney:/home/mike:/bin/bash
alicia:x:10000:10000:Alicia Transue:/home/alicia:
```

and here is her information from ldap search

```
# alicia, people, midfifty.com
dn: uid=alicia,ou=people,dc=midfifty,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: Alicia Transue
sn: Transue
uid: alicia
uidNumber: 10000
gidNumber: 10000
homeDirectory: /home/alicia
```

does mike showing up have something to do with the objectClass? This was just copied from a tutorial so I dont know if those are the correct settings

Comment: Have you checked if there are two accounts with the same UID? That could explain it. The `objectClass`es look correct to me. Could you include the output of `id` when logged in as alicia, please?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by doing an old fashioned restart, why is it that the simplest things that take up your time? Ha. Thanks though @bse